# Splitting a SQL record into a based on field values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record containing the following data

- Contract#
- Starting Odometer
- beginning miles
- end miles
- yearly miles

For the purpose of analysis I am trying to split up the miles driven in a particular 12000 mile range. For example, suppose contract 1 has a starting odometer of 130000 miles and drives 10,000 miles per year. currently my record would look like this

```
contract_num    starging_odo  mi_year year beg_miles    end_miles 
1               130000        10000   1    130000       140000
```

I want to separate the record to look like this

```
contract_num    starging_odo  mi_year year beg_miles    end_miles   band     miles_in_band 
1               130000        10000   1    130000       132000     132000   2000
1               130000        10000   1    132000       140000     144000   8000
```

Comment: Why `2000` and `8000`?  Where these numbers come from?

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear 2000 of the 10000 miles were in the 132000 miles band and the remaining 8000 miles were in the 144000 mile band

Comment: Is the 1st table your source data? What is `band`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I think the miles_in_band in the first row should be 12000, as the maximum 12000 miles are included in the first band (range). The remaining 8000 miles are included in the next band.

Comment: Do you want to split and save the new lines in a new table or you want a query returning this result?

Comment: each band is a bin so the bands are 12000, 24000, 36000, ...
and vehicles with <=12000n and >12000(n-1) miles should be placed in bin 12000n

Comment: @ZacharyLuety The example data that you have provided seems to have discrepancies. If 12000 is the miles in a band, then the entire 10000 mi_year can be included in one band. If I am understanding correctly, if mi_year is 20000 and end_miles is 152000, then 12000 miles would be in first band, 8000 in second. Could you please clarify and correct the post?

Comment: @Joseph B I think bands are 12000 increments starting from 0.  120k to 132k is a band and 132k to 144k is another band.

Comment: @JosephB sorry I could have been more clear. Do you want me to edit anything to make it clearer?

Comment: @ZacharyLuety It's ok. I understand the bands and the splits better now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution that starts by iteratively creating a table that defines the band limits. Once you have that, the rest is fairly straightforward.

```
-- Set up some sample data.
create table [Miles] ([contract_num] int, [starting_odo] int, [mi_year] int, [yr] int, [beg_miles] int, [end_miles] int);
insert into Miles values (1, 130000, 10000, 1, 130000, 140000);
insert into Miles values (2, 130000, 12000, 1, 120000, 132000);
insert into Miles values (3, 130000, 70000, 1, 130000, 200000);

-- Set this variable to the desired band size.
declare @BandSize int = 12000;

-- Create an in-memory table that holds the boundaries of the various bands we need.
declare @MaxMiles int = (select max([end_miles]) from [Miles]);
declare @ThisBand int = 0;
declare @Bands table (band_min int, band_max int);
while @ThisBand <= @MaxMiles
begin
    set @ThisBand = @ThisBand + @BandSize;
    insert into @Bands values (@ThisBand - @BandSize, @ThisBand);
end;

-- Finally, split the records in [Miles] according to band boundaries.
with [DivisionsCTE] as
(
    select
        [M].[contract_num],
        [M].[starting_odo],
        [M].[mi_year],
        [M].[yr],
        case when [M].[beg_miles] > [B].[band_min] then [M].[beg_miles] else [B].[band_min] end as [beg_miles],
        case when [M].[end_miles] < [B].[band_max] then [M].[end_miles] else [B].[band_max] end as [end_miles],
        [B].[band_max] as [band]
    from
        Miles [M]
        inner join @Bands [B] on
            [M].[beg_miles] <= [B].[band_max] and
            [M].[end_miles] >= [B].[band_min]
)
select
    *,
    [end_miles] - [beg_miles] as [miles]
from
    [DivisionsCTE]
where
    [beg_miles] != [end_miles] -- Don't show bands with zero miles.
order by
    [contract_num],
    [band],
    [miles];
```

Results:

```
contract_num starting_odo mi_year     yr          beg_miles   end_miles   band        miles
------------ ------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1            130000       10000       1           130000      132000      132000      2000
1            130000       10000       1           132000      140000      144000      8000
2            130000       12000       1           120000      132000      132000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           130000      132000      132000      2000
3            130000       70000       1           132000      144000      144000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           144000      156000      156000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           156000      168000      168000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           168000      180000      180000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           180000      192000      192000      12000
3            130000       70000       1           192000      200000      204000      8000
```